# Sort files in graphical mode using bash

Tags: bash, sorting, user-interface, terminal, ls

Good morning.

I have the following list of files:

```
3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_00.jpg
3,09AgSec02_01.jpg
3,09AgSec02_02.jpg
3,09AgSec02_03.jpg
3,09AgSec02_04.jpg
3,09AgSec02_05.jpg
3,09AgSec02_06.jpg
3,09AgSec02_07.jpg
3,09AgSec02_08.jpg
3,09AgSec02_09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_0010.jpg
3,09AgSec02_11.jpg
3,09AgSec02_12.jpg
3,09AgSec02_13.jpg
3,09AgSec02_14.jpg
3,09AgSec02_15.jpg
```

In graphical mode I see it fine, but if I do an ls I see it as follows

```
ls -A

3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_00.jpg
**3,09AgSec02_0010.jpg**
3,09AgSec02_01.jpg
3,09AgSec02_02.jpg
3,09AgSec02_03.jpg
3,09AgSec02_04.jpg
3,09AgSec02_05.jpg
3,09AgSec02_06.jpg
3,09AgSec02_07.jpg
3,09AgSec02_08.jpg
3,09AgSec02_09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_11.jpg
3,09AgSec02_12.jpg
3,09AgSec02_13.jpg
3,09AgSec02_14.jpg
3,09AgSec02_15.jpg
```

And to place well (even if I have 00) I use the following form

```
ls -1v 

3,09AgSec02_00.jpg
**'3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg'**
3,09AgSec02_01.jpg
3,09AgSec02_02.jpg
3,09AgSec02_03.jpg
3,09AgSec02_04.jpg
3,09AgSec02_05.jpg
3,09AgSec02_06.jpg
3,09AgSec02_07.jpg
3,09AgSec02_08.jpg
3,09AgSec02_09.jpg
*3,09AgSec02_0010.jpg*
3,09AgSec02_11.jpg
3,09AgSec02_12.jpg
3,09AgSec02_13.jpg
3,09AgSec02_14.jpg
3,09AgSec02_15.jpg
```

All the numbers are sorted correctly, but one of them gives me an error. **'3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg'**

because after 00 and "00 space [A-z]" it shows it at the bottom.

Could it be left as follows?, what it would look like in graphic mode

```
'3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg'
3,09AgSec02_00.jpg
3,09AgSec02_01.jpg
3,09AgSec02_02.jpg
3,09AgSec02_03.jpg
3,09AgSec02_04.jpg
3,09AgSec02_05.jpg
3,09AgSec02_06.jpg
3,09AgSec02_07.jpg
3,09AgSec02_08.jpg
3,09AgSec02_09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_0010.jpg
3,09AgSec02_11.jpg
3,09AgSec02_12.jpg
3,09AgSec02_13.jpg
3,09AgSec02_14.jpg
3,09AgSec02_15.jpg
```

Comment: What is this graphic mode you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by piping it to the [`sort`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) command (or save + `cat` to `sort`) by using the `sort -m` (`sort --merge`) or `sort -z` (`sort --zero-terminated`) on the same list of files. It'll output this:

```
3,09AgSec02_00 Aqui llega el 3-09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_00.jpg
3,09AgSec02_01.jpg
3,09AgSec02_02.jpg
3,09AgSec02_03.jpg
3,09AgSec02_04.jpg
3,09AgSec02_05.jpg
3,09AgSec02_06.jpg
3,09AgSec02_07.jpg
3,09AgSec02_08.jpg
3,09AgSec02_09.jpg
3,09AgSec02_0010.jpg
3,09AgSec02_11.jpg
3,09AgSec02_12.jpg
3,09AgSec02_13.jpg
3,09AgSec02_14.jpg
3,09AgSec02_15.jpg
```

---

Your input (as base64):

```sh
echo MywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMDAgQXF1aSBsbGVnYSBlbCAzLTA5LmpwZwozLDA5QWdTZWMwMl8wMC5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMDEuanBnCjMsMDlBZ1NlYzAyXzAyLmpwZwozLDA5QWdTZWMwMl8wMy5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMDQuanBnCjMsMDlBZ1NlYzAyXzA1LmpwZwozLDA5QWdTZWMwMl8wNi5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMDcuanBnCjMsMDlBZ1NlYzAyXzA4LmpwZwozLDA5QWdTZWMwMl8wOS5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMDAxMC5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMTEuanBnCjMsMDlBZ1NlYzAyXzEyLmpwZwozLDA5QWdTZWMwMl8xMy5qcGcKMywwOUFnU2VjMDJfMTQuanBnCjMsMDlBZ1NlYzAyXzE1LmpwZwo= |base64 -d | sort -z
```

Tried in the [online bash shell](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell).

Comment: Same error using the follow commands:

`$ ls * > aux  

$ cat aux |sort -m |sort -z | head -n 15

$ cat aux |sort -V | head -n 15  :(

Comment: @user1847844 Sorry I meant **or** between those `sort` commands. Nevertheless, each of them works fine in the online bash shell.